# lldb remote debug osx kernel cannot set breakpoint

Tags: macos, debugging, kernel, lldb

I use lldb remote debug osx kernel with kdk through firewire

and set nvram boot-args debug=0x1.When I use

```
br s -a xxxx
```

to set a breakpoint on a driver,it works well.

But if the breakpoint set into the kernel,it is always cannot stop.

So,is there any way to set a breakpoint in osx kernel?

Comment: Are you taking into account the kernel address slide when calculating kernel code addresses? Any reason you're calculating addresses manually instead of setting symbolic breakpoints?

Comment: yes,I am sure the address is correct.And setting symbolic breakpoints gets the same result.

Comment: What does "break list" say after you have set this breakpoint?

Comment: break list is normal

Comment: is that because of the breakpoint is located at a syscall function inside?